# Automatic scroll to bottom of list (displays newest messages entered) using React/Material UI

Tags: reactjs, scroll, material-ui

I am currently designing a chat bot to send messages for sales queries, I am having trouble with making it automatically scroll to the bottom of the list. 
This happens instead: 
[image: How it looks]

Here is my code for the mapping of said messages:

```
<List className={classes.messageArea}>
                                        {chatHistory.map(item => {
                                            return (
                                                <ListItem key={item}>
                                                    <Grid container>
                                                        <Grid item xs={12}
                                                              className={item.sent ? classes.msgsUs : classes.msgsScotti}>
                                                            <ListItemText align={item.sent ? "right" : "left"}
                                                                          primary={item.text}/>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                        <Grid item xs={item.sent ? 11 : 12}>
                                                            <ListItemText align={item.sent ? "right" : "left"}
                                                                          secondary={moment(item.time).format('HH:mm')}/>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </ListItem>
                                            )
                                        })}
                                    </List>
```

How do I get it to automatically scroll to bottom when new messages are sent through, tried various methods but not accomplishing anything. 
Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Answer (score 12):

I've made an example for you. The main thing you need to do is setup a dependency on the list state changing. When this happens you need to scroll the window. One way to do this is with the Element.scrollIntoView() function.

I have included the full example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-microservice-vibw8?file=/src/App.js

The main piece is here, where we run the API function whenever the list changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (scrollRef.current) {
    scrollRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behaviour: "smooth" });
  }
}, [list]);
```

Comment: Thank you, works like charm. Btw, the author should mark as correct answer.